# How to append process name and process to a dict?

Tags: python

**Goal:**

I am aiming to get all process names and process id, to make such output:

```
{process 1: 123},
{process 2: 321},
{process 3: 132}
```

And then id be able to use `.get()` function to get specific `id`.

**Currently:**

I am able to do this:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

list = []
for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  list.append(process.Name)
print(list)
```

Without the process.ProcessId it works fine.

**Errors:**

If I try with process.ProcessId like so:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

list = []
for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  list.append(process.Name, process.ProcessId)
print(list)
```

I get this error:

```
    list.append(process.Name, process.ProcessId)
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

How can I create dictionaries to append these 2 values together into 1 big dict?

Comment: You say you want a dict but create a list... just use `d = {}` instead of `list` and then in the loop a simple `d[process.Name] = process.ProcessId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
processes = {process.Name: process.ProcessId for process in c.Win32_Process()}
print(processes)
```

The most straightforward is to use a list comprehension. Note that duplicate process names will overwrite each other in this scheme; `process.ProcessId: process.Name` would be more foolproof.